# How to responsive and centered google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to embed the google map in size 960x300 ,resposnive and always the marked point in the center. Here is my code. It is responsive but not in right size and when I minimize the marked adresses are not centered.How can I do it?

```
<style>
    .google-maps {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 75%; 
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .google-maps iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
    .gbox{
        width:960px;
        height:300px;

    }
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div class="google-maps">
    <div class="gbox">

        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1XgV0prYhOa2ojHCt-7VcYbLaXnzIICKP" width="640" height="480"></iframe></div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check this solution - https://codepen.io/hubpork/pen/xriIz

Answer (score 0):

Please update this code

```
.gbox{
        width:960px;
        height:300px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    iframe{
        width: 100%;
    }
    @media(max-width:991px){  
        .gbox{
            width:100% !important;
            height:auto;
        }
        .google-maps {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 75%; 
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .google-maps iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!How can I hide this blue header on the top ,I tried this but didnt help iframe{
    width: 100%;
    top:-45px; 
        border:none;
}

Comment: .gbox{ overflow: hidden;}  .gbox iframe{  position: relative; top: -56px;  border: 0px; }